# Calculating Latitude/Longitude X miles from point?

Tags: android

i need to Latitude and Longitude  from current location to north east and south west

Any one have any formula?

Comment: specify the question

Comment: There's a formula on Wikipedia for geographic distance around the globe

Comment: Use function computeOffset from google SphericalUtils. Docs: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/, GitHub: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/5822/154406

Comment: i use mapbox not google Map